# How to specify type in variable assignment via an object in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have variable assignments like:

```
const { namespace, service, version, status } = req.query;
```

How can I specify the types above to each of the variables?

Neither of the following work:

`const { namespace as string } = req.query;`, nor `const { namespace:string } = req.query;`.

Its very weird to write `as` later:

```
await triggerCheck(namespace as string, service as string, version as string, status as string);
```

Its even worse if I have to use the variable multiple times.

Comment: Can't you define an interface or type for `req.query` object?

Comment: I would have expected `req.query` (whatever `req` is) to have types already (and for it to be something akin to `Record<string, string>` so that `namespace` et al would automatically be typed as `string | undefined`. (And since it is, presumably, data coming in from a browser, you can't assume that the query string has everything in it you expect so should write a typeguard to make sure they are defined).

Comment: Supply the generic arguments for `Request`: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/ffc3bfd3716e040f654ade6d4408119796aa611d/types/express/index.d.ts#L113-L119.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify types with certain keys (which you know from `req.query`) like below

```
const { namespace, service, version, status }: { namespace?: string, service?: string, version?: number, status?: string } = req.query as any;
```

*Note that I make all keys optional with `?` because I don't know how you populate `req.query`.*

If all query values are string, you also can use a dynamic key-value pair type like

```
const { namespace, service, version, status }: {[key: string]: string} = req.query as any;
```

Comment: `req.query as any` is need i.e. `const { namespace, service, version, status }: {[key: string]: string} = req.query; as any`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, I went ahead and defined a type for `req.query`,  as:

```
const { namespace, service, version } = router.query as {[key: string]: string}
```

Or, more permanently,

```
export type StrQueryParams = { [key: string]: string };

...

const { namespace, service, version } = router.query as StrQueryParams;
```

Props to *@Nick Vu*'s answer for the generic `{[key: string]: string}`